# Qual o tipo usado no Postgre para salvar um field monetário grande no formato 000.000.000.000.000,00

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em Asp.net e preciso salvar um valor monetário em formato decimal no C# e armazená-lo no postgre em formato numeric, e o valor é grande. É uma necessidade que surgiu no meu sistema...
Estou usando uma máscara de entrada no field  (C#):

```
NomeDoField.mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', { reverse: true });
```

Eu tentei configurar o tipo do field no postgre para numeric(15,2), mas dá erro ao salvar.

Me perdoem pela simplicidade da pergunta, pois é a primeira vez que trabalho com campos assim no C#/Postgre.

Obrigado :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O postgres pode utilizar um tipo monetário personalizado.

A maior capacidade para um tipo personalizado que podemos representar do tipo float (com 2 casas decimais) é o seguinte:

```
create table pagamento(
   id serial primary key,
   valor numeric(1000,2) --representacao maxima
);
```

Segue a documentação que diz:

> Note: The maximum allowed precision when explicitly specified in the type declaration is 1000; NUMERIC without a specified precision is subject to the limits described in Table 8-2.

Em uma tradução livre seria:

> A precisão máxima explicitamente especificadas na declaração do tipo é 1000; Numeric sem uma precisão especificada está sujeita aos limites descritos na tabela 8-2.

Link para a [tabela 8-2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE)

Fora esses tipos personalizados ainda é possível utilizar o tipo money.

Segue a documentação para o tipo money: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Danizavtz!!! Funcionou perfeitamente agora! Sou muito grato :)